# getView() method in custom list adapter is not being used

Tags: android, custom-lists

Hi I've been trying to use a custom list activity with a custom list item layout and I'm in desperate need for assistance. My custom adapter class which I use as the list adapter may be wrong or right but whatever it is the method getView() is not being used and when I put logs in it it doesn't show, my adapter class is this :

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    int position1;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource,int pos) {
        super(context, resource);
        position1 = pos;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.privatep_single_list_item, parent, false);
        String[] general_Items = new String[Items.length()] ;
        String[] financial_Items = new String[Items.length()] ; 
        String[] address_Items = new String[Items.length()] ; 
        StringBuilder general_sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder financial_sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder address_sb = new StringBuilder();
        if(position1 == 0){
        try{
        for(int i = 0; i < Items.length(); i++){

                general_sb.append(Items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Area").toString());
                general_sb.append(" متر ");
                general_sb.append(Items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Bedrooms").toString());
                general_sb.append(" خواب ");
                general_sb.append(Items.getJSONObject(i).getString("CA").toString());
                general_sb.append(" ساخت ");

                financial_sb.append("متری ");
                financial_sb.append(Items.getJSONObject(i).getString("OPPM").toString());
                financial_sb.append(" تومان");

                address_sb.append(Items.getJSONObject(i).getString("address").toString());

                general_Items[i] = general_sb.toString();
                financial_Items[i] = financial_sb.toString();
                address_Items[i] = address_sb.toString();

        }}
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
        }
        } else if (position1 == 1){

            try{
                for(int i = 0; i < Items.length(); i++){

                        general_sb.append(Items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Area").toString());
                        general_sb.append(" متر ");
                        general_sb.append(Items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Bedrooms").toString());
                        general_sb.append(" خواب ");
                        general_sb.append(Items.getJSONObject(i).getString("CA").toString());
                        general_sb.append(" ساخت ");

                        financial_sb.append("کرایه ");
                        financial_sb.append(Items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Rent").toString());
                        financial_sb.append(" /n");
                        financial_sb.append("رهن ");
                        financial_sb.append(Items.getJSONObject(i).getString("PrePayment").toString());

                        address_sb.append(Items.getJSONObject(i).getString("address").toString());

                        general_Items[i] = general_sb.toString();
                        financial_Items[i] = financial_sb.toString();
                        address_Items[i] = address_sb.toString();

                }}
                catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
                }
        } else if (position1 == 2){
            try{
                for(int i = 0; i < Items.length(); i++){

                        general_sb.append(Items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Area").toString());
                        general_sb.append(" متر ");
                        general_sb.append(Items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Bedrooms").toString());
                        general_sb.append(" خواب ");
                        general_sb.append(Items.getJSONObject(i).getString("CA").toString());
                        general_sb.append(" ساخت ");

                        financial_sb.append("رهن ");
                        financial_sb.append(Items.getJSONObject(i).getString("Price").toString());

                        address_sb.append(Items.getJSONObject(i).getString("address").toString());

                        general_Items[i] = general_sb.toString();
                        financial_Items[i] = financial_sb.toString();
                        address_Items[i] = address_sb.toString();

                }}
                catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
                }
        }


        TextView general_text = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.General_Info);
        TextView financial_text = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Financial_Info);
        TextView address_text = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Address_Info);

        general_text.setText(general_Items[position]);
        financial_text.setText(financial_Items[position]);
        address_text.setText(address_Items[position]);

        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
}
```

and here is my adapter's construction

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.privatep);
    setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,0));

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.select_Spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.select_Options_personal, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


}
```

I will much appreciate your comments on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this -> `return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);`
you should probably return the variable row because that is the ui view you really built yourself. `return row;` in your getView() method

Comment: Thanks , but my problem is that it doesn't call the getView() method in the first place. do you know if my constructor is wrong or something?!

Comment: It doesn't seem like you have added any data to MyAdapter.